# Knockout.js - ObservableArray not returning values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In knockout, this works and binds correctly:

```
self.currentCustomer = ko.observable(new Customer("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"));
```

However, the below does not.

```
// Random list of customers
self.customers = ko.observableArray([
    new Customer("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
]);


self.currentCustomer = ko.observable(self.customers[0]);
```

I cannot figure out why this is not working. This pattern in working correctly in other parts of my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the array, you must unwrap it:

```
self.currentCustomer = ko.observable(self.customers()[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to that, the View is as below:

```
<p>Customer Name <input data-bind="value: currentCustomer().name" /></p>
```

The model is as below:

```
function AppViewModel() {
   // Random list of customers
self.customers = ko.observableArray([
    new Customer("ABC Corp.")
]);


self.currentCustomer = ko.observable(self.customers()[0]); // This is the correction.

}


function Customer(_name)
{
    this.name = ko.observable(_name);
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```